# Have different font colours in the same Aquamacs document

Tags: aquamacs

I am writing a document in Aquamacs, and I want some (not all) of the text to be in a different colour. Is this possible?

I googled it but could only see how to change the font colour of all the text.

Comment: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_as_word_processor.html and http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FaceMenuPlus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite unclear. Please specify. What do you mean by putting some of the text in a different color?

- Do you want syntax-specific highlighting? If so, turn on font-locking. And you might need to define `font-lock-keywords` for the current mode. See the Emacs manual, node [Font Lock](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html).
- Do you want ad hoc highlighting? If so, try the [Highlight library](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)).
- For information about font coloring and faces, see Emacs Wiki, Category [Faces](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryFaces). Or ask Emacs: `C-h r` `C-h i faces RET`.